# Show object for 5 seconds and load new scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making mobile game in which I need to show text message for 5 seconds after destroying object. I tried with yield waitforseconds but doesn't work. I also tried with Invoke function. I created a separate function with line code SceneManager.LoadScene ("__Main1"); but I have the same problem.

I want to show my text for 5 seconds, and then, load new scene.

This is my code now:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
    {


        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("bomb")) {
            other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
            scoretext.SetActive (true); //this text need to be displayed for 5 seconds after destroying game object
            SceneManager.LoadScene ("__Main1");

        }
```

I hope that someone can help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot destroy the object and start coroutine on it. You need for that other object that has reference to this text, and stays active while is performing coroutine.

EDIT:

To be more precise:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("bomb")) {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);

        scoretext.SetActive (true); //this text need to be displayed for 5 seconds after destroying game object
        waitEndDisable.WaitAndDisable(scoretext); // here we go ;)
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }
```

On other script, that is runing on **active** GameObject:

```
public void WaitAndDisable(GameObject obj)
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndDisableCoroutine(obj));    
}

IEnumerator WaitAndDisableCoroutine(GameObject obj)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("__Main1");
    obj.SetActive(false);
}
```

As you can see in your main script you need a reference to the script with **WaitAndDisable** method. Make sure this object is active (gameObject.activeSelf == true).

Comment: Ok, but how in my case. I tried everything all day.

Comment: Edited, sorry for the code outside, but couldnt do anything about it.

Comment: this line is in red color         waitEndDisable.WaitAndDisable(scoretext); // here we go ;)  on my code. I attached new script on text element. (because i need show text and keep them for 5 seconds)

Comment: waitEndDisable is a reference to **your script** with methods I showed you ;)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. I have no idea. I think it's problem with my text object. I'm trying to show score at end of level and keep them for 5 seconds, but nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enumerator for wait for seconds.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("bomb")) 
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        StartCoroutine(Foo());
    }
}

IEnumerator Foo()
{
    scoretext.SetActive (true); //this text need to be displayed for 5 seconds after destroying game object
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("__Main1");
}
```

you should add using System.Collections for using enumerators.

Comment: if you say what didn't work people can help more I think